# Notification content unchanged

Tags: android, notifications

I need a persistent notification for a never-ending service. At the moment, I have that but I don't see any of the content or intents I associate with the notification. The notification comes up saying "App is running - Tap for more information or to stop the app" and after tapping, I'm taking to the app info page where I can uninstall/force stop. Am I doing something wrong in my code:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
    .setContentTitle(APP_NAME)
    .setContentText(NOTIFICATION_CONTENT)
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    .setOngoing(true)
    .build();
notification.flags = notification.flags | Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;

startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```